# Что будет, если открыть уже открытый файл?

Tags: c++

Что будет, если открыть уже открытый файл?

Comment: А вы уже пробовали? И что было?

Comment: Открывать можно по разному: на чтение / на запись;

Answer (score 5):

Зависит от того, какие share-флаги были выставлены при открытии файла в первый раз. Например, если был выставлен только share-флаг запрета на запись и во второй раз выполняется открытие на чтение -- то всё хорошо, если же открываем на запись -- получаем ошибку нарушение прав доступа, открыть не получится.

Пример, здесь мы запрещаем повторное открытие на запись:

```
FILE *FP = _fsopen("filename".txt", "a+", _SH_DENYWR);
```

Константы _SH_Xxx определены в share.h -- не забудьте добавить `#include <share.h>`

[_fsopen, _wfsopen в MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8f30b0db.aspx)

Как я понял, вас особо интересует обработка ошибок.
Прежде всего, проверяем, не равен ли результат 0. Если нет -- то это корректный file pointer. Если 0 -- то смотрим чему равен errno.